# Recent Badges list on the front page suggestion

Tags: feature-request, badges, homepage

The list often just gets filled up with "Yearling" badges which isn't overly exciting and it could perhaps be more useful if it was presented like the Recent Tags list which has the `tag x #` format.
The only downside is that you wouldn't get your name printed on the page, but I personally find that seeing really interesting badges being dished out is far more exciting/inspiring/click-able...

**Old View:**

```
Necromancer awesome_user  
Tenacious   awesome_user 2  
Yearling    awesome_user 3  
Yearling    awesome_user 4  
Yearling    awesome_user 5  
Yearling    awesome_user 6
```

**Suggested view:**

```
Necromancer x 2  
Tenacious x 4  
Fanatic x 7  
Enthusiast x 3  
Yearling x 567
```

It's great and even inspiring seeing the unusual badges being awarded to people and I feel this could highlight that a bit more... And you get to see who it was recently awarded to on the badge page itself, so that information hasn't been lost either.

Answer (score 5):

I think the best approach is half-way: `Yearling` badges are common, and can be grouped (or even hidden - there are currently 37801 of them). For other badges, it is nice to see your name on the front page, and even names of others (!).

Answer (score 1):

As it is, the list really isn't scalable, so I agree that a slight refactoring may be in order.

First off, I think it's important to keep the user names in the list.

Since most of the space is taken up by the badges themselves, maybe group by the badge type, and show a list of users who received the badge. It would display the same information as we get now, just in a more space-efficient way.

```
[Necromancer]
  awesome_user
[Tenacious]
  awesome_user 2
[Yearling]
  awesome_user 3, awesome_user 4,
  awesome_user 5, awesome_user 6
```

(Not an exact design, obviously.)

Assuming we continue to show the user names in the list, *no* design will be truly scalable, but I think this kind of design would put off that eventuality quite a bit longer.